# Redirect to https unless from private network on nginx

Tags: nginx

I'd like to redirect all request coming from outside the network to https - but keep internal one s on http.

Right now I have two `.conf` files - one that begins so:

```
server {
        # listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot                                                                                                                                              
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot                                                                                                                                                                 
        server_name www.example.com , example.com;         
        # omitted stuff
}
```

and contains

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com , example.com;         
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

and another that begins like this:

```
server {                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        listen 192.168.1.144:80;                                                                                                                                                                             
        listen 192.168.1.196:80;                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        server_name "";                                                                                                                                                                                      
        root /var/www/html;                                                                                                                                                                                  
        # omitted stuff
   }
```

But right now requests to http://example.com do not get redirected to https.

Why is that? what have I gotten wrong? my goal is to redirect all requests not coming from the home private network (`192.168.1.*`) to https, and leave internal ones alone.

Answer (score 2):

`server_name` directive uses spaces for separating domain names. Your configuration has commas, which confuses nginx.

You need to use:

```
server_name www.example.com example.com;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that with the following you are trying to make a different server block that listens on two interfaces on the local network:

```
server {
    listen 192.168.1.144:80;
    listen 192.168.1.196:80;
    # ...
}
```

For this to work your topology would look similar to this:

[image: Topology with Nginx directly connected to the Internet]

However, if your server is behing the same NAT than the clients on the private network `192.168.1.0/24`, this `server` block would be used for the external connections, too. This topology would be similar to this:

[image: Topology with NAT & port forwarding]

With the latter, you could use e.g. the [ngx_http_geo_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) to separate the local network based on its clients:

```
geo $external {
    default         1;
    192.168.1.0/24  0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/html;
    
    if ($external) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

However, from the security perspective I wouldn't recommend trusting your internal network like this, but using TLS equally for every client. That's because it's easy to get MitM position simply by having access to the local network.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the redirect, and for the internal I personally prefer to make server name by IP address.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.key;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location{
       .......
    }
}
```